# sequences of six digits (0-9)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many sequences of six digits(0-9) contain at least one 3, at least one 5 , and at least one  8? Can someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that there $10^6$ sequences of $6$ digits.

Next, note that the question is equivalent to requesting the complement of the number of six digit sequences that contain no $3$s, or no $5$, or no $8$'s.

We recall that:
$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| -|B\cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|$$

Now, let $A = \{\text{sequences with no $3$'s}\}$, $B = \{\text{sequences with no $5$'s}\}$, and  $C = \{\text{sequences with no $8$'s}\}$.

Then:
$$\begin{align}
|A| &= 9^6 \\
|B| &= 9^6 \\
|C| &= 9^6 \\
|A\cap B| &= 8^6 \\
|A\cap C| &= 8^6 \\
|B\cap C| &= 8^6 \\
|A\cap B\cap C| &= 7^6 \\
\end{align}$$

Thus, the number of such sequences is:
\begin{align}
10^6 - |A\cup B\cup C| &= 10^6-(|A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| -|B\cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|) \\
&=10^6 - 3(9^6) + 3(8^6) - 7^6 \\
&= 74460
\end{align}

Comment: I understand what you're doing using the inclusion - exclusion principle it's just that the answer 74,670 and i'm not sure how to get that.

Comment: Hm.  I'm not entirely sure.  I think I'll wait for some other, much better combinatorics person to come along... :)

Comment: I do understand you though, I'm just trying everything to try to get that answer. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: No, there are $10^6$ sequences of six digits. Your later calculations get this correct-$9^5$ and so on.

Comment: :headdesk: wow.   I can't believe I did that.  Thanks,  @RossMillikan.  (Editing now)

Comment: Also watch the signage of the exclusion-inclusion, especially after taking the complement.